# typhead not populating angular ui

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-ui-typeahead, angular-components

- Angular 1.5.8
- Bootstrap 3.3.7 (CSS)
- Angular-ui 2.0.2

Using angular Typeahead ([ui.bootstrap.typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)) requires a list of objects which it will display in the ui component with HTML

**Problem**

1. Returning `promise` from service to component (*1.5 style controller, view, bindings*)
2. Controller function uses the returned `promise` from the service and performs the `then` logic and returns the `array` of objects
3. Typeahead does not process the array... performing a console log, you can see the array.
4. If I statically pass the same array of objects **without** using the service method then the functionality works

**HTML**

```
            <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.search.term" ng-disabled="!$ctrl.search.type"
                   typeahead-wait-ms="600"
                   placeholder="Search..."
                   uib-typeahead="res as res.name for res in $ctrl.submit($viewValue)"
                   typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control" required>
            <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="icon ion-refresh"></i>

            <div ng-show="noResults">
                <i class="icon ion-close"></i> No Results Found
            </div> 

            <select class="form-control custom-select-md"
                   ng-model="$ctrl.search.type"
                   placeholder="Type"
                   required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Type?</option>
                <option value="car">car</option>
                <option value="van">van</option>
            </select>
```

**Component (controller, view )**

```
//submit search for issuers or issuedCard
submit() {
    this.isSubmitting = true;

    this._SearchService.performSearch(this.search)
    .then(
        (resp) => {
            //e.g. [{id:1, name:'test'}]
            console.log('Search Result', resp);
            return resp;                                
        },

        (err) => {
            console.log('Error Search', err);
            this.reset(false);
            this.errors = err;
            return [];
        }
    );

    //Comment out method above to see this static data returning and working as should be :'(
    //return [{id:865,issuer: {},name:"British Testing"},
    //    {id:866,issuer: {},name:"American Testing"}];
}
```

**Service**

```
performSearch(searchData) {
    console.log('Search Qry', searchData);

    let deferred = this._$q.defer();

    if(!this.isValidSearch(searchData)) {
        deferred.reject({status:400,  error: 'Bad Request', message:'invalid data'});
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    let searchURI = (searchData.type === 'car' ? 'van' : 'issuer');

    this._$http({
        url: `${this._AppConstants.api}/${this._AppConstants[searchURI]['search']}`,
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            name: searchData.term
        }
    }).then(
        (resp) => {
            console.log('Search Data', resp);
            this.result.term = searchData.term;
            this.result.type = searchURI;
            deferred.resolve(resp.data[this._AppConstants[searchURI]['searchResp']]);

        },

        (err) => {
            console.log('Error performing search', err);
            deferred.reject(err.data);
        }
    );

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using

```
res as res.name for res in $ctrl.submit($viewValue)
```

What comes after the `in` is supposed to be an array, or a promise of array.

But it's not. It's what returned by `$ctrl.submit()`. And this method doesn't return anything:

```
submit() {
    this.isSubmitting = true;

    // no return here

    this._SearchService.performSearch(this.search)
    .then(
        (resp) => {
            //e.g. [{id:1, name:'test'}]
            console.log('Search Result', resp);
            return resp;                                
        },

        (err) => {
            console.log('Error Search', err);
            this.reset(false);
            this.errors = err;
            return [];
        }
    );

    // no return here
}
```

The only return statements return from the function passed to `then()`, and are executed **asynchronously**, after the `submit()` method has returned nothing (i.e. `undefined`).

So, to be short, you need to return the promise:

```
return this._SearchService.performSearch(this.search) ...
```

Note that your service method could be reduced and cleaner if you used promise chaining, instead of the resolve/reject anti-pattern:

```
performSearch(searchData) {
    console.log('Search Qry', searchData);

    if(!this.isValidSearch(searchData)) {
        return $q.reject({status:400,  error: 'Bad Request', message:'invalid data'});
    }

    let searchURI = (searchData.type === 'car' ? 'van' : 'issuer');
    return this._$http.get(`${this._AppConstants.api}/${this._AppConstants[searchURI]['search']}`,   { params: {name: searchData.term) } }).then(
        resp => {
            console.log('Search Data', resp);
            this.result.term = searchData.term;
            this.result.type = searchURI;
            return resp.data[this._AppConstants[searchURI]['searchResp']]);
        }).catch(resp => {
            console.log('Error Search', err);
            this.reset(false);
            this.errors = err;
            return $q.reject([]);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I don't think you've understood what is returned? I can see perfectly fine in the console that there is an array of objects being received in the controller and is returned to the view.
[example screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/ltQG4).
Service returns the promise `deferred.promise`, which is the API results and is an array of objects `[{id:1, name:'testing'},{id:2, name:'testing 2'}]`. The controller receives this promise and processes via the `then` success/error handlers (omitted some of the further processing verbosity purposes) and returns the array to the view

Comment: No. It doesn't return an array. Re-read my answer. The callback functions passed to then() return an array. But the submit() method doesn't return anything. And it can't possibly return an array, since the array is obtained **asynchronously**, using a promise. So it could (and should) return a promise of array, but it doesn't: it returns nothing. If it did, your typeahead would work fine, and you wouldn't have asked your question. Just because an array is printed inside the code of a function doesn't mean that this array is returned from the function. Those are two very different things.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding :/ ... thanks for your time, much appreciated! I'm a Java/Groovy guy haha... still getting my head around JS. I added the return simply to the controller on the service method  and that works... my head just doesn't quite understand why though. You mention that submit doesn't return anything... why didn't the fact that I was returning from within the then error or success handler count? Can't believe how much time I've spent on this silly issue :/

Comment: Here's a Java method to help you understand: `void submit() {executor.submit(() -> { return 42; });}`. The method returns void, so it doesn't return anything, right. Yet it contains a return statement. The return statement returns from a function (a lambda implementing Callable, in this case) that is passed to an executor so that this executor calls this function, later, in a different thread. It's basically the same here: you pass a function to then(), so that this function is executed, later, when the promise returned by the service is resolved, i.e. when the http response comes back.

Comment: I have written a blog post explaining promises and chaining that has proven helpful for many: http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Comment: Wow, thank you ever so much... I feel like such a dummy :D you are a gentlemen and a scholar sir, great explanation... only 2 years into the dev world